# Stop lsyncd changing my target directory ownership

Tags: permissions, rsync, sftp

I'm using `lsyncd` to copy some files from `/dir1` to `/home/myuser`. I'm using the `rsync` options to `chown` the files when they are transferred, but what seems to be happening is as well as changing the individual files ownership, the target directory also has it's ownership changed too.

What I would like to happen is the files get their ownership changed, but the target directory is left alone and not changed at all.

My `/home/myuser` is owned by `root:root`, and I'd like it to stay that way as the directory is used as the home directory for an SFTP user. It seems that when a file is transferred the `/home/myuser` directory ends up being owned by `myuser:myuser`, which stops from logging in via SFTP.

This is my lsyncd config:

```
settings = {
    logfile = "/var/log/lsyncd/lsyncd.log",
    statusFile = "/var/log/lsyncd/lsyncd.status"
}

sync {
    default.rsync,
    source = "/dir1",
    target = "/home/myuser",
    delete=false,
    rsync = {
        _extra = {"-og","--chown=myuser:myuser","--remove-source-files"},
    }
}
```

I'm using v2.1.5 of `lsyncd`.

It is entirely possible that I'm just misunderstanding how this all works as I am very new to Ubuntu coming from a Windows environment, so apologies upfront if this is a stupid question!